# compare rows and print the same values for the same rows

Tags: r, perl, awk

I have an input like this:

```
A  118791136  X 
A  118791136  x 
A  118791136  X 
A  118791136  X 
B  118791136  x 
B  23456433   X 
B  23456433   X
B  23456433   x
.
.
.
```

I would like to convert it to an output like:

```
A  118791136  XxXXx
B  23456433   XXx
.
.
.
```

I know a little bit perl, but I do not know how to compare row by row

Thank you very much in advance

AND if we have

```
A  118791136  X 
A  23456433   x
B  34222223   X
B  56444233   X
```

How it is possible to have an output like this:

```
A 118791136,23456433 X,x
B 34222223,56444233 X,X
...
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This piece makes it:

```
$ awk '{a[$1,$2]=a[$1,$2]$3} END{for (i in a) {print i, a[i]}}' file
B118791136 x
A118791136 XxXX
B23456433 XXx
```

Just stores the result in an array, having 1st and 2nd fields as indexes. At the end, it prints the result.

The result gives `B23456433` instead of `B 23456433`, trying to split it... `sed` makes it:

```
$ awk '{a[$1,$2]=a[$1,$2]$3} END{for (i in a) {print i, a[i]}}' file | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/\1 /'
B 118791136 x
A 118791136 XxXX
B 23456433 XXx
```

#### Update based on [sudo_O's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273941/compare-rows-and-print-the-same-values-for-the-same-rows/18273996?noredirect=1#comment26806140_18273996)

```
$ awk '{a[$1,$2]=a[$1,$2]$3} END{for (i in a) {split(i,b,SUBSEP); print b[1], b[2], a[i]}}' file
B 118791136 x
A 118791136 XxXX
B 23456433 XXx
```

#### Update based on new comment

> @fedorqui is it possible to add a counter, somehow count the number of
>   the same rows in a column?

```
$ awk '{a[$1,$2]=a[$1,$2]$3} END{for (i in a) {split(i,b,SUBSEP); print b[1], b[2], a[i], length(a[i])}}' file
B 118791136 x 1
A 118791136 XxXX 4
B 23456433 XXx 3
```

Comment: You already got my +1 however `sed` is not needed. The correct approach is to used [**SUBSEP**](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_87.html) like `awk '{a[$1,$2]=a[$1,$2]$3}END{for(k in a){split(k,b,SUBSEP);print b[1],b[2],a[k]}}' file`

Comment: @fedorqui would you please tell me which book, tutorial in AWK programming can help me to learn this stuff?

Comment: @sudo_O uhms, thanks, I wasn't aware of the existence of such option. Updated!

Comment: @MaryamSani I have mostly learnt from [so], asking and answering :) Also, http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ was very helpful for some tricks (sudo_O recommended it to me).

Comment: @MaryamSani You want to read [Effective AWK Programming](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/)

Comment: @fedorqui is it possible to add a counter, somehow count the number of the same rows in a column?

Comment: @MaryamSani so the output would be like `A 118791136 XxXX 4`, for example? Check my updated answer

Comment: @fedorqui I tried to solve another issue but I could not. Would you please have a look at the last part of the question that I just added. Thanls

Comment: @MaryamSani, `awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]","$2; b[$1]=b[$1]","$3} END{for (i in a) {print i"-"a[i]"-"b[i]}}'` file can make it.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/^((.*)\s+\S+)\s*\2\s+/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```