# overlay rows based on common values from sequential rows

Tags: r, perl, awk

I have an input like:

```
A  200-400  213  253  295  350  0011
A  200-400  260  295  315  000
A  200-400  205  263  295  111
B  800-900  801  832  840  843  870  890  895  00110101
B  800-900  801  823  850  010
B  800-900  850  1
.
.
.
```

0 and 1 values in the last columns are corresponding to the values from the third columns to the last one

I would like to generate a tab-separated matrix like the following:

```
A 200-400  NA   213  253  NA   NA   295  NA   350 
A 200-400  NA   NA   NA   260  NA   295  315  NA
A 200-400  205  NA   NA   NA   263  295  NA   NA 
B 800-900  801  NA   832  840  843  NA   870  890 895 900
B 800-900  801  823  NA   NA   NA   850  NA   NA  NA  NA
B 800-900  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   850  NA   NA  NA  NA
```

at the end, replace 0 and 1 values with corresponding values and

```
A  200-400  NA  0    0    NA   NA   1    NA    1 
A  200-400  NA  NA   NA   0    NA   0    0     NA
A  200-400  1   NA   NA   NA   1    1    NA    NA 
B  800-900  0   NA   0    1    1    NA   0     1   0   1
B  800-900  0   1    NA   NA   NA   0    NA    NA  NA  NA
B  800-900  NA  NA   NA   NA   NA   1    NA    NA  NA  NA
```

thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? Note that you posted a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273941/compare-rows-and-print-the-same-values-for-the-same-rows and you could re-use some of the code.

Comment: Anybody has the magic wand?

Comment: How are you filling with NAs here? And please correct the typo in your title.

Comment: @fedorqui I do not know how to write it. I am learning perl and R but but I am too far away to write it.

Comment: I can see *no* connection between the `00100` patterns and the distribution of `NA`s. Please formulate an explicit algorihm that explains what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Arun first 3 rows are in the same range. So, if we order the values from smallest to largest, 205 would be the smallest which there is no corresponding value in the first and third rows (NA)

Comment: @amon in the second step I want to replace 0,1 values with the corresponding values in each row. e.g. in A  200-400  213  253  295  350  0011, 213 belongs to 0, 253 --> 0, 295 -->1, 350 -->1

Comment: @amon I want to somehow overlay rows based on common values and If there is no values, take into account as unknown(NA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a fun question. I will answer in Perl.

We need to read in all lines of the same range at once. Each number in these ranges must also remember what line they came from. Then, we can sort the numbers of each range, and re-assemble the lines.

For the first range, we would have a collection of values like

```
[213 => 1], [253 => 1], [295 => 1], [350 => 1],
[260 => 2], [295 => 2], [315 => 2],
[205 => 3], [263 => 3], [295 => 3],
```

We should de-duplicate common numbers, so that we get

```
[213 => 1], [253 => 1], [295 => 1, 2, 3], [350 => 1],
[260 => 2], [315 => 2],
[205 => 3], [263 => 3],
```

(order is not important).

We can sort these items by the first field:

```
my @sorted = sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @items;
```

For each line, we can then iterate through the sorted items, and decide by the line number if we print an `NA` or a number:

```
for my $line (1 .. 3) {
  my @fields = map { decide_if_number_or_na($line, @$_) } @sorted;
  ...
}

sub decide_if_number_or_na {
  my ($line, $number, @lines) = @_;
  return $number if grep { $line == $_ } @lines;  # ... if any of the lines is our line
  return "NA";
}
```

Of course, we should emit the correct `0` or `1` value right away.

Tying all of this together is a bit complicated. During parsing of the input, we need to associate each line with the current `01` patterns, remember the first two fields, and build the data structure for the items.

The resulting code follows the above considerations, but takes a few shortcuts: Once they are ordered, the actual value of each number is not important for our items, and we can discard it.

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature 'say';

my @lines;   # an array of hashes, which hold information about each line
my %ranges;  # a hash mapping range identifiers to number-to-occuring-line-array hashes

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($letter, $range, @nums) = split;  # split everything into field ...
  my @pattern = split //, pop @nums;    # but the last field is a pattern, which we split into chars.
  push @{ $ranges{$range}{$_} }, $. for @nums;  # $. is the line no
  push @lines, {
    letter  => $letter,
    range   => $range,
    pattern => \@pattern,
    line    => $.,
  };
}

# simplify and sort the ranges:
for my $key (keys %ranges) {
  my $nums2lines = $ranges{$key};  # get the number-to-occuring-lines-array hashes
  # read the next statement bottom to top:
  my @items =
    map { $nums2lines->{$_} }  # 3. get the line number arrayref only (forget actual number, now that they are ordered)
    sort { $a <=> $b }         # 2. sort them numerically
    keys %$nums2lines;         # 1. get all numbers
  $ranges{$key} = \@items; # Remember these items at the prior position
}

# Iterate through all lines
for my $line (@lines) {
  # Unpack some variables
  my @pattern = @{ $line->{pattern} };
  my $lineno  = $line->{line};
  my $items   = $ranges{$line->{range}};

  # For each item, emit the next part of the pattern, or NA.
  my @fields  = map { pattern_or_na($lineno, @$_) ? shift @pattern : "NA" } @$items;
  say join "\t", $line->{letter}, $line->{range}, @fields;
}

sub pattern_or_na {
  my ($line, @lines) = @_;  # the second value (the specific number)
  return scalar grep { $_ == $line } @lines;  # returns true if a number is on this line
}
```

Which produces the desired output.

This is quite complicated code, especially for a beginner. It makes use of Perl references and *autovivifiction*. Also, I use many list transforms like `sort`, `map` or `grep`. This solution does not take into account that lines with the same range are continuous, so I wouldn't have to keep everything in memory. This solution is simpler (sic!) but uses more memory than neccessary.

I recommend reading the `perlreftut`, `perlre`, and `perldsc` manpages in order to understand all of this.